# Add collaborators on the title page for beamer class

Tags: beamer

How can I add collaborators on the title page when using the beamer class? Please do NOT suggest me to use the \author option, since I'd like it to be displayed in the style of:

> In collaboration with
>
> Author a, Author b, etc

Another question is how can I add logos for their institutes?

That is, the title page should be displayed as follows:

[image]

Here's an example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt][beamer]

\title[TITLE]

\author[AUTHOR]{Author} 

\institute[INSTITUTE][institute\\\\

\textit{email}]

%%I'd like to add the collaborators here.

%%Here the logos.

\date[\today]{Meeting}
```

Comment: Can you please add a small example code which shows us which theme you use? Please also add a sketch how you want the collaborators and their logos to be positioned.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your example code does not use any theme, I'm going to assume you use the default theme. You can redefine the title page of this theme like this to add as much extra information as you like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\title[TITLE]{title}

\author[AUTHOR]{Author}

\institute[INSTITUTE]{institute\

%%I'd like to add the collaborators here.

\textit{email}}

\date[\today]{Meeting}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
      
      Institute
      
      \bigskip
      
      In collaboration with
      
      Author a, Author b, etc
      
      \includegraphics[width=1cm,page=3]{example-image-duck}\quad\includegraphics[width=1cm,page=42]{example-image-duck}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]